# How to target jquery.load data with a variable and output it contents

Tags: jquery, ajax

We all know that jQuery haves a structure like this in its official page for example `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` ([see link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)), but how do we access the data part of that structure and make sure it's linked to `jquery.load` data part?

Would someone share a piece of code example rather than saying where I should go? It just my code document is situation based rather than document based.

So the problem is that the var data is suppose to output its string when the button is pressed and it does that because it is making reference to that AJAX div id call div1, But the way the code is currently is that it shows that var data on page load instead I want to make sure it loads because of the jquery.load code.

Here's my code.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//url
var url ="response_files/2.php"

//data
var data ="This is an AJAX data response"
document.getElementById("show_load_data_string").innerHTML = data;

    $("#start_load").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load(url,data);
    });
 $("#start_load").click(function(){
        $("#start_load").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<p id="show_load_data_string"></p>
<br>
<button id="start_load" >Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**response_files/2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>HELLO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so specifically using `.load()` appears to work as follows:

```
$( "#feeds" ).load( "feeds.php", function() {
  alert( "The last 25 entries in the feed have been loaded" );
});
```

So anything within the function will occur after the load.  If you need to retrieve the loaded data, it seems like you should just be able to get the contents of element with ID feeds.  This could be done with

```
$("#feeds").html()
```

Comment: well I already know that you can do that with $.get but why do they have that structure with $.load for example $.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] ) i'm just trying to see how I can do that with $.load. since the official jquery document said you can do that so that documentation makes it obvious that you can do that on their website I'm doing this to master understanding  $.load. and its structure.